# IBM Worklight - Getting an error on project creation

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I have installed Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers and installed the IBM Worklight Plugin successfully.

The icon for Worklight is being shown up in my Toolbar. Now when I click on Worklight Project and then Further on Hybrid Mobile App option, it doesn't work at all. It just stops and if I click any other option, it displays this message:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>   com/worklight/studio/mobilemarketplace/plugin/handlers/TemplateHandler

What should I do?

Comment: Which OS is it? Which Eclipse version are you using? Which version of Worklight?

Comment: I'm using Windows 8 (64-bit).
Eclipse 4.3.0
IBM Worklight Developer Edition V6.1

Comment: Try with 4.3.1 (Worklight supports 4.2.2 and 4.3.1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use either Eclipse Jave EE 64bit 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2) or 4.3.1 ("Kepler" SR1). These are the Eclipse versions supported by Worklight.

Steps:

1. After extracting Eclipse, use it with a new workspace
2. Then install the Worklight Studio plug-in from Eclipse > Help >  Eclipse Markpetplace
3. Once installed, click the Worklight icon from the toolbar
4. Provide a project name
5. Choose "Hybrid Application" > click Next
6. Provide an application name > click Finish

The above process successfully created a new Worklight project and application for me.